# How to preserve original resolution of scanned 1-bit PDF raster with gdal_translate?

Tags: gdal, pdf, raster-conversion, gdal-translate, geotiff-tiff

I am using [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to convert non-spatial PDFs to non-spatial TIFFs (intended for subsequent manual georeferencing).

This is my `gdal_translate` command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds -co NBITS=1 --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 300 %input_pdf% %output_tif%
```

Here is what it looks like at ~8x magnification (note the "nibbling" around the edges of text and the complete loss of many "speckles"):

Input (rendered by Adobe Reader, disregard the slight blurring of edges):

[image: Input]

Output (rendered by ArcMap):

[image: Output]

If I do not specify the output bit depth (by omitting the `NBITS` option), I can tell that GDAL is re-rasterizing and resampling the input 1-bit image into a blurred grayscale image:

[image: Resampled]

Ideally it would just copy each pixel in the input straight to the output.

How can I retain the original resolution without information loss in the output? Should I use something else, like ImageMagick, Poppler or GhostScript?

All this re-rasterization GDAL is doing is painfully slow, I might add, so I think I will try one of the alternatives for that reason alone.

Comment: I've always used ghostscript for this sort of task though many will balk at using command line options, there was GSview (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/) that went with ghostscript that offered a GUI to export with.

Comment: I typically use Adobe products (Photoshop/Acrobat) directly for this sort of thing, but I gather you're looking for a free or at least less costly solution. At one point I had a problem trying to extract jpgs because every Adobe method I tried invariably altered the image (recompress, etc). It was suggested to me to try [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) as that would allow me to 'extract the exact image, bit for bit, as it is in the pdf.' I have yet to get around to testing it though.

Comment: Just saw that our very own @mattwilkie had a very similar question over on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693820/386205 Seems this is a common GIS workflow :)

Comment: Oh, veeeery common, at least in some fields. I do this a lot with plats and surveys. For some reason everyone wants everything as a pdf, even if all the pdf is doing is serving as a container for an image(s).

Comment: Yup. The nice things about PDF are just about everyone has a reader for it, and it is a multi-page format. The same cannot be said for many other formats. It's sad that ArcGIS cannot import PDF files directly. Well, [it can](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39752), but only on the page layout, and with shoddy results to boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), suggested by @ChrisW, but I couldn't get its `pdfimages` command to actually do anything.

However, [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/)'s `mutool extract` command worked great. It produces PNGs rather than TIFFs, but that should be fine. The resolution appears unchanged from the original.

I was also able to get [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) working for this purpose, although I had to specify the output resolution (300 dpi):

```
gswin32c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tifflzw -r300 -sOutput
File=%output_tif% %input_pdf%
```

I will probably go with GhostScript as I have more control over the output naming convention and the 1-bit TIFF files it produces with the above command are smaller than the 8-bit PNGs MuPDF produces.

Comment: I guess the crux of the matter is the distinction between *converting* a pdf to tif vs *extracting* an image from one. As you noted in gdal, and even when using Photoshop and some methods in Acrobat, conversion ends up re-rasterizing the data. As far as Xpdf, not sure if [pdfimages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html) was the command you would want to use as opposed to [pdfdetach](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=pdfdetach&ampsect=1). It may depend on what image format went into the pdf, and I've yet to get around to testing it.

Comment: Yup, it's just one big scanned image per page in the PDF. The GhostScript command above works surprisingly quickly though. `gdal_translate` was orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: `pdfdetach -saveall` doesn't seem to do anything either. `pdfdetach -list` says there are no embedded files. Strange.

Comment: I determined `pdfdetach` is for a different purpose - think markups and acutal attachments like to an email. `pdfimages` is the correct command. I got it working (in fact all you need is that exe, nothing else). The command line was `pdfimages c:\path\filename.pdf c:\path\outputfolder\nameprefix` which generated a numbered series of images. Output path is required or it won't do anything. It only outputs three formats (ppm, pbm, or jpg) per the link above, so conversion/compression still required if not using `-j` (just like MuPDF and PNGs). I'll be checking those other two out myself.